# print Perl hash key value (key is an array)

Tags: perl, hash, key

Hi I have a Perl hash defined as:

```
foreach my $pair (@correlatedPttns)
{    
   # slice the data out
    my @tmp = ();
    for (my $x = 0; $x<$cnt; $x++)
    {    
        push @tmp,[ @{ $data[$x] } [ 0, @$pair[0], @$pair[1] ] ]; # epochtime, Pi, Pj
    }    

    #build hash
    $pairToDataHash{Dumper(@$pair)} = \@tmp;
}
```

If output the hash, print Dumper(\%pairToDataHash), it will looks like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '$VAR1 = 30; 
$VAR2 = 31; 
' => [


                                       [     
                                        'TIME',
                                        'P30',
                                        'P31' 
                                      ],    
                                      [     
                                        '1398038853',
                                        '0',  
                                        '0'   
                                      ],
```

How do I get the individual keys because the key was formed as an array via Dumper. I need to access the value $VAR1=30. How do I get the element of keys?

```
for ( keys %pairToDataHash)
{
      #get the key element value. 
}
```

Comment: What are `@correlatedPttns`, `@data`, and `$cnt`? Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place?

Comment: Your subject line says `print Perl hash key value (key is an array)` but a Perl hash key can only be a simple C string: it is not even a Perl string.

Answer (score 1):

Data::Dumper is a debugging tool. It's not appropriate to use here.

It looks like you have pairs of integers, so just use

```
$pairToDataHash{ join ':', @$pair }
```

and

```
for ( keys %pairToDataHash ) {
   my @pair = split /:/;
   ...
}
```

If you have floating point numbers instead, use

```
$pairToDataHash{ pack 'd*', @$pair }
```

and

```
for ( keys %pairToDataHash ) {
   my @pair = unpack 'd*';
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Without commenting on whether your scheme hash keys could be improved upon ...

Output from `Data::Dumper` is suitable to be passed to Perl's `eval` function.

```
for ( keys %pairToDataHash)
{
    my ($VAR1,$VAR2);     # required for 'use strict'
    eval $_;
    ... now $VAR1, $VAR2 are loaded
}
```